# Error when adding case statement using date paramaters "Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int"

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a query, the goal is to allow a user to pass start and end dates to select customer sales withing the range. Additionally there are two sub queries, one that gets the first order date of a customer and another that gets the last order date of a customer prior to the selected date range.

The query works fine until I add a case statement that attempts to create some customer groupings based on new customer status as well as customer reboarding status.

I have tried redesigning the subqueries a few times but I think the problem is in the case statement. Regarding the aliases the current configuration is a little confusing, the subqueries are stacked not joined individually so the naming conventions are strange but again, the query works until I try to add the case statement.

Unfortunantely, I don't know enough to see what the problem might be, so any help will be greatly appreciated. Case statement is below.

The error returned is

> Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int

Code:

```
CASE 
   WHEN LAST_ORD.FIRST_ORDER BETWEEN @START_DATE AND @END_DATE 
      THEN 'NEW IN SELECTED PERIOD'
   WHEN LAST_ORD.FIRST_ORDER <= @END_DATE - 365 
      THEN 'NEW IN LAST YEAR'
   WHEN LAST_ORD.LAST_ORDERED < @START_DATE - 730 
      THEN 'REBOARDED 2+Y INACTIVE'
   WHEN LAST_ORD.LAST_ORDERED < @START_DATE - 365 
      THEN 'REBOARDED 1+Y INACTIVE'
   ELSE 'ACTIVE CUSTOMER'
END AS CUST_HIST
```

Comment: you need to use `DATEADD(DAY` not `-` with `date` datatype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need `dateadd`

```
CASE WHEN LAST_ORD.FIRST_ORDER BETWEEN @START_DATE AND @END_DATE THEN 'NEW IN SELECTED PERIOD'
   WHEN LAST_ORD.FIRST_ORDER <= DATEADD(day,- 365,@END_DATE ) THEN 'NEW IN LAST YEAR'
   WHEN LAST_ORD.LAST_ORDERED < DATEADD(day,- 730,@START_DATE )  THEN 'REBOARDED 2+Y INACTIVE'
   WHEN LAST_ORD.LAST_ORDERED < @DATEADD(day,- 365,@START_DATE )THEN 'REBOARDED 1+Y INACTIVE'
   ELSE 'ACTIVE CUS
```

Comment: Thank you Zaynul, that did the trick and I learned something new today!